# Split a python pandas column using positional string in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe with the structure:

| ID | Split | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | GT:RC:BC:CN | 1:4:5:3 |
| 2 | GT:RC:CN | 1:7:0 |
| 3 | GT:BC | 4:2 |

I would like to create n new columns and populate with the data in the Data column, where n is the total number of unique fields split by a colon in the Split column (in this case, this would be 4 new columns: GT, RC, BC, CN). The new columns should be populated with the corresponding data in the Data column, so for ID 3, only column GT and BC should be populated. I have tried using string splitting, but that doesn't take into account the correct column to move the data to.

The output should look like this:

| ID | Split | Data | GT | RC | BC | CN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | GT:RC:BC:CN | 1:4:5:3 | 1 | 4 | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | GT:RC:CN | 1:7:0 | 1 | 7 |  | 0 |
| 3 | GT:BC | 4:2 | 4 |  | 2 |  |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
out = df.join(pd.concat([pd.Series(d.split(':'), index=s.split(':'))
                         for s,d in zip(df['Split'], df['Data'])], axis=1).T)
```

output:

```
   ID        Split     Data GT   RC   BC   CN
0   1  GT:RC:BC:CN  1:4:5:3  1    4    5    3
1   2     GT:RC:CN    1:7:0  1    7  NaN    0
2   3        GT:BC      4:2  4  NaN    2  NaN
```